# Merge cells are getting unmerged on cells double click of RadGridview

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I am using telerik's RadGridView for merged cells functionality.I am merging cells in vertical direction. The cells of same value are being merged but when double clicked on merged cell, these cells are getting separated.

Is there any way to prevent this unmerging of cells on double click?

I have tried capturing cell double click event and handling it but it does not stop.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score -4):

Try the following style, this will help in handling mouse click on merged cell

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewMergedCell">
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
</Style>
```